# internet explorer 7 hover drop down menu

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, menu, drop-down-menu

i have created a simple drop down menu only with css, its working fine in all browsers except internet explorer 7, when i hover to menu link it shows drop down items but when mouse moves away from the link the drop down items disappears, how can i fix it ?

Answer (score 2):

When this happens to my menus, it's usually because there is a space between the element that's being temporarily displayed on :hover, and the element that triggered the temporary display.

Do you have a link or some sample code?

Comment: thnx, im working locally , it has many codes, but i am using some margin and padding , when i remove them its working fine, but i need some space to move the drop down items to bottom

Answer (score 1):

You basically need to `display` the `a` element as a `block` element with a zero `margin`.

```
ul li a {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
}
```

To give the elements some inner space, just use `padding` instead.